# java and python gives different result in logical operator

Tags: java, python, logical-operators

I am trying to get broadcast ip address coding in Java and Python for practice. Here is my code in java which gives me correct output:

```
public IPv4Address getBroadcastAddress() throws IllegalArgumentException {
    long bits = 0;
    bits = this.address.decimalIP() ^ (~(0xffffffff ^ (1L << 32 - getMaskLength()) - 1));
    IPv4Address broadcast = new IPv4Address(bits);

    return broadcast; 
}
```

Here `decimalIP` is the number representing IP address, `getMaskLength` - number representing its mask. Here I got expected broadcast address.
By in python using the same logic I got unexpected results:

```
def broadcastaddress(self):
    return IPv4Address(self.address.decimalip ^ (~(0xffffffff ^ (1 << 32 - self.mask) - 1)))
```

Here all components represent the same entries as in java. After debugging I got that number `(~(0xffffffff ^ (1 << 32 - self.mask) - 1))` is negative. In documents operator `~` gives inversion in bits but I don't understand why this number is negative in Python and not in Java?

Comment: I would start off by simplifying things a lot - get rid of all the calls etc and hard-code the values into short but complete programs in each of Java and Python. Then make each step a separate statement, so you can see *exactly* which operation has different behaviour.

Comment: In java you can simplify (~(0xffffffff ^ (1L << 32 - getMaskLength()) - 1)) => (~(~(1L << 32 - getMaskLength()) - 1))

Comment: @sol4me: which returns the same thing as `(1L << 32 - getMaskLength()) - 1)`. And one should use one's complement, not two's complement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python integers are not bounded and are not signed, so `~` creates a negative number:

```
>>> hex(~(0xffffffff ^ (1 << 32 - 24) - 1))
'-0xffffff01'
>>> ~(0xffffffff ^ (1 << 32 - 24) - 1)
-4294967041
```

However, `~` in Java would give you the *two's complement*, while the operation on the subnet mask requires a *one's complement*, which can be achieved by using `XOR` on the netmask. Since that'd *undo* the *other* `XOR` operation you already applied, you don't need to use the 1's complement here **at all**:

```
return IPv4Address(self.address.decimalip ^ ((1 << 32 - self.mask) - 1))
```

I suspect that you could just use [`IPv4Network.broadcast_address`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Network.broadcast_address) here:

```
network = IPv4Network('{}/{}'.format(self.address.decimalip, self.mask)
return network.broadcast_address`
```

Comment: I have a small doubt in your answer, As far as I suppose `~` is same in both languages (i.e. both give a negative number). The problem is only with `^` the reason being stated in your answer. Do correct me if I am wrong. Ty.

Comment: @BhargavRao: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking there. I sidestepped the issue mostly because the calculation of the broadcast mask is a lot simpler.

Comment: I'm not asking about the goal which is to calculate the broadcast mask. The OP asked the difference between `~` in Java and Python, With regard to his question and his line of code, what I think is that the problem lies in `0xffffffff` and not `~`. So I just asked you to clarify on this point.

Comment: @BhargavRao: right, I don't think there is a difference other than that the Java type used for `getMaskLength` the must've been unsigned.

Comment: I made a dummy program to run from 0 till 2147483648 that is 1 more than the limit in Python. I was surprised that till then the numbers are negative. The number was not unsigned. It works on unsigned numbers. What my thoughts are telling me is that the number `0xffffffff` used must be `0xfffffff` until the number `1073741824` and then `0xffffffff`. The problem is (as you have said) numbers are bounded in Python.

Comment: @BhargavRao: Python integers are *un*bounded. `sys.maxint` is *not the limit*, your memory is.

Comment: `sys.maxint` doesn't exist any more I'm telling that thanks to the variable size of Python integers, Till `1073741824` integers are 28b. SO we need to use 7`f`s in the OP's command. Whereas from that number the size is 32b. So we need to use 8`f`s in the OP's command. All my arguments are in favor of OP's command used.

Comment: @BhargavRao: `sys.maxint` exists in Python 2 still. The moral equivalent in Python 3 is `sys.maxsize`. Note that integers have a `.bit_length()` method; you can use that to create a suitable mask instead of manually working out the length. In IP addresses, you generally always work with 4-byte masks anyway.

Comment: Thanks, Got the problem. We hafta mask the integer to the required length. This removes all the errors between Py and Java. Sorry for taking your time, but had a good and fruitful experience. Thanks again.

Comment: @BhargavRao: but for a `/24` network, the network mask is `0xffffff00`, so `0xffffffff ^ 0xff` is the correct procedure to produce that. The broadcast mask is the one's complement of that, so `0x000000ff` again. Much easier to just produce that with `(1 << 32 - self.mask) - 1` than complementing twice.

Comment: Yeah that is much much better. Otherwise, we would have some really screwed up code.